# Merging nested If in C# (Short Circuit Keywords in C#)

Tags: c#, language-features, conditional-statements

Is it possible to merge the following statement:

```
if (a != null)
{
  if (a.Count > 5)
  {
     // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

to just 1 If statement and make it not to check the second condition when the first one is not satisfied. (like `AndAlso` keyword in VB.NET). something like:

```
if (a != null /* if it is null, don't check the next statement */ &&& a.Count > 5)
{
   // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Try this: `If((a!=null) && (a.count>5)){do stuff}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply:

```
if ((a != null) && (a.Count > 5)) {
    // ...
}
```

In C#, the `&&` operator [short-circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning it only evaluates the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression is true (like VB.NET's `AndElse`).

The `And` keyword you are used to in VB.NET does *not* short-circuit, and is equivalent to C#'s `&` (bitwise-and) operator.

(Similarly, `||` also short-circuits in C#, and VB.NET's `Or` is like C#'s `|`.)

Comment: If a=null, it throws an exception. doesn't it?

Comment: @Cameron: A little off-topic, but do you happen to know of any language in which `&&` *doesn't* short-circuit?

Comment: @Kamyar: No, that's what he means by short-circuits: If the first condition is false, the second isn't evaluated.

Comment: Hmm strange. Thought I tried it and didn't get the result! Thanks anyway folks.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The only one that comes to mind is VB, but then, it doesn't make use of the `&&` operator ;-)

Comment: Do note that the `AndAlso` keyword in VB.NET (the one shown in the question) **does** short circuit. `And` does not, for backwards compatibility reasons; it's intended to be used as a bitwise AND in VB.NET, much like C#'s `&`.

Comment: Similarly, `OrElse` is the VB.NET equivalent of C#'s `||`. It also performs short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `&&` operator to short-circuit the if statement:

```
if (a != null && a.Count > 5)
{
     // Execute code 
}
```

So, if a is `null` then there is no need to evaluate the second condition for the if statement to return a value of `false` and therefore not execute the code in the block.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((a != null) && (a.Count > 5)) // Parentheses are nice, but not necessary
{
  // Excitement goes here
}
```

In C#, `&&` [is indeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) a "short circuit" operator — if the expression to its left is false, the expression to its right will not be evaluated.